# Verificar URL para incluir metatags

Tags: php, jquery

Preciso verificar a url de um site, se ela for igual www.teste.com.br/agenda, a *meta name="description"* vai ser "blablabla", se for www.teste.com.br/home vai ser "teste".
Como faço a verificação da URL?

Comment: Não estou vendo diferença nas 2 urls....

Comment: @Francisco editei

Comment: diferença na rota?

Comment: @miltoncamara Eu só quero que quando o cliente acesse a página /home a description seja diferente de quando ele acessar a página /agenda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a variável `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, ela pega o URI fornecido para acessar a página atual:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/agenda"){
    echo"<meta name='description' content='Agenda Description'>";
}
else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/home"){
    echo"<meta name='description' content='Guia de Caxias do Sul'>";
}
```

Comment: Assim funcionaria também?
<? if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/agenda") { ?>
<meta name="description" content="Agenda Description">
<? } else { ?>
<meta name="description" content="Guia de Caxias do Sul">
<? } ?>

Comment: Eu recomendaria tacar tudo direto no php, editei minha resposta, da uma olhada.

Comment: Eu me enganei. A home do site não tem /home, é só o site mesmo.
O description está sendo incluso na página /agenda, mas o ideal seria excluir o antigo.

Comment: Se não tem o home, acredito que o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` irá retornar `"/"`